# HTTP Auth over SSL secure?

Tags: authentication, ssl, hash

we actually try to implement a secure way to get some local files over a webserver. as vpn can't be used, what do you think about http authentication over ssl and a e.g. php script, that serves a local fie based on an extra api hash-key?

is http authentication over ssl secure?

thanks!

Comment: i meant secure, sorry! edited everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Secure** is a very subjective word, and needs to be factored against the motivation and/or resources of a would-be attacker.  If what you're doing is unlikely to attract the attention of a motivated organisation with plenty of computing resources, the answer is *probably*, based on sensible selection of key size, algorithms, etc.

The biggest risk to the security of anything over SSL is probably keeping your private key private. :)